# Swapping elements in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsmutablearray, swap

Are there any special methods to make swapping elements in an NSMutableArray easier or more direct?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

[exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BCIJIGDB) does exactly this.